# How to reflect changes in viewmodel to tableviewcell view with binding in MVVMcross

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Am a little stuck with getting changes reflected from the ViewModel to the View when used in a `MvxBindableTableViewCell`. I am using the vNext branch of MvvmCross on iOS.

Everything is set up properly and the initial values are visible when loading/showing the list for the first time. The list is a `ObservableCollection<T>` and the ViewModels inherit from `MvxViewModel` (thus implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

The main ViewModel looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel, IMvxServiceConsumer
{
    //... just regular implementation
}

public class UploadListViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly IUploadItemTasks uploadItemTasks;
    private readonly IPhotoPickerService photoPickerService;

    public IObservableCollection<UploadItemViewModel> Uploads { get { return this.LoadUploadItems(); }  }

    public UploadListViewModel()
    {
        this.uploadItemTasks = this.GetService<IUploadItemTasks>();
        this.photoPickerService = this.GetService<IPhotoPickerService>();
    }

    private IObservableCollection<UploadItemViewModel> LoadUploadItems()
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWork.Start ())
        {
            return new SimpleObservableCollection<UploadItemViewModel>(uploadItemTasks.GetAll());
        }
    }

    public void StartUpload ()
    {
        if (this.Uploads == null || this.Uploads.Count == 0) {
            ReportError("Error", "No images to upload");
            return;
        }

        this.Uploads.ForEach (uploadItem => PostCallback (uploadItem));
    }

    private void PostCallback (UploadItemViewModel uploadAsset)
    {
        IProgressReporter progressReporter = uploadAsset;

        this.photoPickerService.GetAssetFullImage(uploadAsset.ImageUrl,
                                                  (image) => {
            UIImage fullImage = image;
            NSData jpeg = fullImage.AsJPEG();

            byte[] jpegBytes = new byte[jpeg.Length];           
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(jpeg.Bytes, jpegBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(jpeg.Length));

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(jpegBytes);
            Uri destinationUrl = new Uri(uploadAsset.DestinationUrl + "&name=" + uploadAsset.Name + "&contentType=image%2FJPEG");

            //TO DO: Move this to plugin
            var uploader = new Uploader().UploadPicture (destinationUrl, stream, UploadComplete, progressReporter);
            uploader.Host = uploadAsset.Host;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (delegate {
                uploader.Upload ();                 
                jpeg = null;
            });
        });
    }

    private void UploadComplete (string name)
    {
        if (name == null){
            ReportError("Error","There was an error uploading the media.");
        } else 
        {
            //ReportError("Succes", name);
        }
    }
```

The item ViewModel looks like:

```
public interface IProgressReporter
{
    float Progress { get; set;} 
}

public abstract class BaseAssetViewModel: BaseViewModel, IBaseAssetViewModel
{
    //... just regular properties 
}

public class UploadItemViewModel: BaseAssetViewModel, IProgressReporter
{
    public UploadItemViewModel(): base()
    {
    }

    private float progress;
    public float Progress {
        get {
            return this.progress;
        }
        set {
            this.progress = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => Progress);
        }
    }
}
```

The View for the items inherits from `MvxBindableTableViewCell` and has the property:

```
private float progress;
public float ProgressMarker {
    get {
        return progress;
    }
    set {
        progress = value;
        // change progressbar or textfield here
    }
}
```

The tableviewcell is bounded to the `UploadItemViewModel` via the BindingText:

```
public const string BindingText = @"ProgressMarker Progress, Converter=Float;";
```

The `Uploader` class mentioned in the snippet of `UploadListViewModel` implements a private method which tries to set the progress on the IProgressReporter.

```
    float progressValue;
    void SetProgress (float newvalue)
    {
        progressValue = newvalue;

        this.dispatcher.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
            if (ProgressReporter != null)
                ProgressReporter.Progress = progressValue;
        });
    }
```

During the first viewing of the list I can see that the properties in both the ViewModel and View are being hit but when I update the ViewModel via the interface `IProgressReporter` with a new value in `Progress` the View in the tableviewcell is not updated nor the property is being called.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing here?

**UPDATE:** Check the answer to this question.

Comment: Is there a bit more code you can post? Maybe a gist including what the class of the item is in your list and the bit of your ViewModel that contains that list. Also, I'm getting confused here by the `Mode=TwoWay` bit - just checking that I'm not misunderstanding what you are asking about.

Comment: I updated my question with some more code. Hopefully it is more clear now. The `Mode=TwoWay` part I removed because that was a remnant of some testing. It should be `OneWay` only; from ViewModel to View.

Comment: Thanks - I can't see anything wrong. I'm going to try to get a repro tomorrow (but time is against me)

Comment: Can I ask one thing? Can you check the cell's ProgressMarker `set` is not being called? e.g. add some trace to it. The only `long shot` I can think of is that `SetNeedsDisplay()` is not enough to cause the redraw (that's normally for custom `Draw` methods?)

Comment: I've put a trace in the `set` of ProgressMarker and it shows that is only being called during initial viewing. I also put a trace in the `set` of Progress in the `UploadItemViewModel` which gets updated nicely but the view doesn't get the updates. Looks like the propagation of the property change is not done or that bindings are out of sync? And it is true that `SetNeedsDisplay()` is only necessary for redrawing for a custom draw, so i removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why the binding didn't work. I was replacing the ObservableCollection over and over again..  I changed that piece of code as stated below and now it reflects the changes made to the UploadItemViewModel in the View of the cell.

```
    private IObservableCollection<UploadItemViewModel> uploads;
    private IObservableCollection<UploadItemViewModel> LoadUploadItems()
    {
        if (uploads == null)
        {
            using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWork.Start ())
            {
                uploads = new SimpleObservableCollection<UploadItemViewModel>(uploadItemTasks.FindAll());
            }
        }
        return uploads;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Remco for self-answering! I built a v3 case yesterday - and it worked... so I was going to try v2 today... but now I don't need to :)